# Unable to access credentials in awscli for boto3 - Window 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have `credentials` and  `config` in my .aws (its in home directory )with contents inside it. Still facing below issue while running code

```
translate = boto3.client(service_name='translate', region_name='us-east-1', use_ssl=True)
```

When doing below its throwing error ...

```
translate.translate_text()
```

botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: ('Unable to locate credentials', 'occurred at index Unnamed: 0')

When hardcoding , its working

```
translate = boto3.client(
    service_name='translate',
    aws_access_key_id='XXX',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXXXX',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    use_ssl=True
)
```

When working on `mac` I am not facing any issue .Only in Window I got stuck..

Comment: The credentials should be in `/home/<USER>/.aws/` folder. Does that exist in your machine ?

Comment: Yes, its there . However when passing secret key and id  in  boto3.client() manually it works..

Comment: can you edit the question to include the few lines before and after the code ?

Comment: Are you running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance, or on your own computer?

Comment: trying to use boto3 for translate..

Comment: @kintuparantu Please check the edit now..

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Please check the updated question with small code

Comment: Are you running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance, or on your own computer (not on EC2)?

Comment: Own computer ..

Comment: Have you run `aws configure` and entered your credentials?

Comment: It was already done, when setting it up initially ..

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to be setup correctly. Please run `aws configure` again and enter your credentials.

Comment: Let me try it again..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178846/discussion-between-stevej-and-john-rotenstein).

Comment: Go the same issue.

Comment: for windows it should be in ```C:\Users\<USER>\.aws\``` folder.

Comment: Its there , still i have the issue ..